# embed a tiktok video onto an app page with flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

Video player, webview, custom widgets on pubdev, all seem to be failing me on what should be a simple problem... how do i display a tiktok video on a page using flutter widgets? Embarassed to admit how long I have tried to code this.

I have tried the html-editor widget too.

Coding/interface is via flutterflow.